# How To Export State From Another module of reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We are starting to work on a project as 3 students who are new to react. I wanted to split the code so everyone could work on something at once. But when I tried to use a state from icon-bar.js in App.js I got error messages.
App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import IconBar from './components/icon-bar';
import Events from './components/events';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 className="Title">ENAKS</h1>
      <IconBar />
      <Events />
  <div className="mainModeFrame"><p1>{this.state.mode}</p1></div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

icon-bar.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import '../App.css';

class IconBar extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            mode: 'Hi'
        }
    }
    render() {
        return(
                <div className="icon-bar">
                <div className="iconHolder">
                <img src="/images/2dlogo.png" alt="" className="icons" onClick={() => this.setState({mode: '2d'})}/>
                <img src="/images/3dlogo.png" alt="" className="icons" onClick={() => this.setState({mode: '3d'})}/>
                <img src="/images/flag.png" alt="" className="icons" onClick={() => this.setState({mode: 'edit'})}/>
                <img src="/images/tracker.png" alt="" className="icons" onClick={() => this.setState({mode: 'track'})}/>
        <div>{this.state.mode}</div>
                </div>
         </div>
              )
    }
}


export default IconBar;
```

How can I use my "mode" state to change my p1 in the App.js

Comment: check out redux.

Comment: @CiBoz I was drafting my answer. Answered below.

Comment: put mode in parent comp state and pass as prop in render `<IconBar mood={this.state.mood} />` and access in child comp with `this.props.mood`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finding the correct component to hold your state is important.   Here you want to move your mode to the parent component state and access it from child component as a prop.

I see your child component is setting mode which is a little tricky since it will now be held in the parent state, so how to do that ?

You create a callback in the parent and set that callback as a prop when you call your component in the parent render.

You will then need to set your onClick event handler on each image element to call an event handler (in this case handleClick) in your child component.

This event handler will then grab the id of the target element and pass that to the parent using this.props.onUpdateMode  (the callback that we passed as a prop).

The parent callback receives the data from the child, and updates state accordingly.

Reference: [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import IconBar from './components/icon-bar';
import Events from './components/events';

class App() extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            mode: null
        }
        this.updateMode = this.updateMode.bind(this);
    }

  updateMode = (newMode) => {

      this.setState({mode: newMode});
  }


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 className="Title">ENAKS</h1>
      <IconBar onUpdateMode={this.updateMode}  mode={this.state.mode} />
      <Events />
  <div className="mainModeFrame"><p1>{this.state.mode}</p1></div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

---

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import '../App.css';

class IconBar extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.handleClick=this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick(e) {

      let mode = e.target.id;
      this.props.onUpdateMode(mode);

    }


    render() {
        return(
                <div className="icon-bar">
                <div className="iconHolder">
                <img src="/images/2dlogo.png" id="2d" alt="" className="icons" onClick={this.handleClick} />
                <img src="/images/3dlogo.png" id="3d" alt="" className="icons" onClick={this.handleClick}/>
                <img src="/images/flag.png" id="edit" alt="" className="icons" onClick={this.handleClick}/>
                <img src="/images/tracker.png" id="track" alt="" className="icons" onClick={this.handleClick}/>
        <div>{this.props.mode}</div>
                </div>
         </div>
              )
    }
}


export default IconBar;
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked flawlessly. Just one thing. I couldn't get this.props.mode to render correctly. Even though it compiled without and error the div in IconBar returns empty. Where my poblem might be. (I updated the code a little.)

Comment: if you console.log(e.target.id) in the handleClick method, is the correct mode showing up in console?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this.

The first one is to use something like redux. where you have global store for the state which can be shared across different components.

The second one would be to emit the state in the parent component. Here Icon bar should be child component to your parent component `app.js`. From parent component you pass function as a props and that function should take an argument which could be state

Below Icon bar takes props now (see constructor and super)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import '../App.css';

class IconBar extends Component {
    constructor(props) { // 
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            mode: 'Hi'
        }
    }
    render() {
        return(
                <div className="icon-bar">
                <div className="iconHolder">
                <img src="/images/2dlogo.png" alt="" className="icons" onClick={() => this.setState({mode: '2d'})}/>
                <img src="/images/3dlogo.png" alt="" className="icons" onClick={() => this.setState({mode: '3d'})}/>
                <img src="/images/flag.png" alt="" className="icons" onClick={() => this.setState({mode: 'edit'})}/>
                <img src="/images/tracker.png" alt="" className="icons" onClick={() => this.setState({mode: 'track'})}/>
        <div>{this.state.mode}</div>
                </div>
         </div>
              )
    }
}


export default IconBar;
```

and then in app.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import IconBar from './components/icon-bar';
import Events from './components/events';

function App() {
   const getStateFromChild = state => {
  // body of function 
  // return something 
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 className="Title">ENAKS</h1>
      <IconBar  upsideEmit={getStateFromChild} />
      <Events />
  <div className="mainModeFrame"><p1>{this.state.mode}</p1></div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When do you want the state to be sent to the parent component depends on you.

**[Update:]** I do something very similar in one of my [open source repo](https://github.com/irohitb/rn-formly/). instead of navigating through the entire code, [look at this line](https://github.com/irohitb/rn-formly/blob/master/index.js#L168)

Here I have a parent component, In which I have child component `Checkboxes`

```
<CheckBoxes 
  options={options}
  upsideEmit={onChangeHandler}
  defaultColor={defaultColor}
  />
```

CheckBoxes is passed a function onChangeHandler  `upsideEmit={onChangeHandler}` (ignore the body of the function)

```
const onChangeHandler =  (data, errorMessage=null) => {
    // Error Message is usually passed from the child components (look ad date componenet example )
    if (!errorMessage && (data === '' || data)) { // Doing data = "" in case someone want to remove last char of a string
      const currentData = {...payload}
      currentData[key] = data
      setPayloadData(currentData)
    } else if (errorMessage) {
      setErrorData({status: true, message: errorMessage})
    }
    return
  }
```

Now, If you look at this [line](https://github.com/irohitb/rn-formly/blob/4d6b0d52cbcc86ff4535a5bfa0fc5edf96010c75/formComponent/checkbox.js#L77) in checkboxes component, I am passing my child state to parent component

```
  const toggleState = (index) => {
    let copyState = [...state]
    const previousState = copyState[index]['value']
    if (multipleSelect) {
      // Setting all other values as false, since the array for checkbox won't in normal scenario be big, we can just iterate and set it to false
      copyState = copyState.map(element => {
        element.value = false
        return element
      })
    } 
    copyState[index]['value'] = !previousState 
    setState(copyState)
    upsideEmit(copyState)
}
```

If this helps, please give the repo a star.

Comment: Well, this is a good answer though. I think the second option, emitting the state in the parent component sound like a good start. If app grows and state management becomes a mess. Take a look at redux.

Comment: Is there something spesific I need to write in to the getStateFromChild in order to get the this.state.mode. I couldn't make it work. (This is my first full on react project sorry.)

Comment: The other answer solved my problem but code looks a lot cleaner. I will be trying it in a few hours. Thanks.